# LinkedIn Posts API response is OK but post not showing

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

This issue only occurs with posts with multipart video, Posts with images and videos below 4MB are working, when posting to Posts API i get a response with Status OK and the post URN in the header but when i try getting the post data using the given URN i'm getting error 404.

Here is the function that i am using to upload the video to LinkedIn.

```
const uploadVideo = async (linkedinId, accessToken, videoUrl) => {
  /* Fetching video from Google storage */
  const videoData = await axios.get(videoUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
  const contentType = videoData.headers['content-type'];
  const videoSize = videoData.headers['content-length'];

  const url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/videos';
  const body = {
    initializeUploadRequest: {
      owner: `urn:li:organization:${linkedinId}`,
      fileSizeBytes: Number(videoSize),
    },
  };

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
    'x-li-format': 'json',
    'LinkedIn-Version': 202207,
  };

  const response = await axios.post(url, body, { headers, params: { action: 'initializeUpload' } });
  const { uploadInstructions } = response.data.value;
  const asset = response.data.value.video;

  /* Uploading video */
  try {
    const uploadPromises = uploadInstructions.map(async ({ uploadUrl, firstByte, lastByte }) => {
      const arrayBuffer = videoData.data.slice(firstByte, lastByte);

      return axios({
        url: uploadUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: arrayBuffer,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': contentType,
        },
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        maxContentLength: Infinity,
      });
    });

    const uploadResponses = await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    const finalizeUploadBody = {
      finalizeUploadRequest: {
        video: asset,
        uploadToken: '',
        uploadedPartIds: uploadResponses.map((uploadResponse) => uploadResponse.headers.etag),
      },
    };

    await axios.post(url, finalizeUploadBody, {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      params: {
        action: 'finalizeUpload',
      },
    });

  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  return asset;
};
```

Here is the function that i am using to publish the post to LinkedIn.

```
const publishContent = async (
  linkedinId,
  accessToken,
  media,
) => {
  const url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts';
  const body = {
    author: `urn:li:organization:${linkedinId}`,
    commentary: 'content',
    visibility: 'PUBLIC',
    lifecycleState: 'PUBLISHED',
    distribution: {
      feedDistribution: 'MAIN_FEED',
    },
  };

  const asset = await uploadVideo(linkedinId, accessToken, media.urls[0], isPage);

  body.content = {
    media: {
      title: 'Title',
      id: asset,
    },
  };

  const headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
    'x-li-format': 'json',
    'LinkedIn-Version': 202207,
  };

  return axios.post(url, body, { headers });
};
```

Comment: the post may take a few seconds upto 1 minute to display

Comment: I checked back 24h+ later but it still is 404

Comment: then the video was rejected, ensure it has the correct width/height ratio, frames per second and also the file size...

Comment: fps must be 29 per second

Comment: try my [script](https://pastebin.com/UMyWRVCX)

Comment: I was able to fix it, the issue was that the second argument in ArrayBuffer.slice is not inclusive so i had to add 1 to it, Thanks for the help!